# How to specify source address for source-specific multicasting in Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gio

I'm trying to set up a gstreamer1.0 client to receive a source specific multicast.  It's clear how to set the group ip for the multicast, but I don't see any properties to set the source address.  http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-udpsrc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it.  Set the uri property in the following format:
udp://172.22.200.54@239.130.110.108:10108'

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-bugs/2011-June/079642.html